# Mongodb with Grafana

Tags: mongodb, grafana

I'm trying to add new Query to MongoDb via Grafana, but I get an error.

If I try with the next simple query:

```
 db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
     {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" : "2020-03-03", "_id":0 }}
     ])
```

I get: `"doc.ts.getTime is not a function"`

And if I try to convert date string to date type:

```
db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
 {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" :  {$toDate:"2018-03-03"}, "_id":0 }}
 ])
```

I get: `"Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 81"`

I also have tried:

```
 {$dateFromString: { dateString: "2016-03-04T04:07:55.144Z", timezone: “America/New_York”}
```

and

```
{$Convert{ input:  "2018-03-03", to: "date" }}
```

But I can't get it work.
The queries work with MongoDb Console, but not in Grafana.
Can anyone help?

**EDIT: I found solutions. It seems to look that converting string to date-type in Grafana MongoDb plugin does not work. Maybe it is not suppored. 
I changed string time to real date-type when I added it to Mongo database. Then I don't have to convert it in query.**

```
 db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
         {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" : "$date", "_id":0 }}
         ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions.

It seems to look that converting string to date-type in Grafana MongoDb plugin does not work. Maybe it is not suppored. I changed string time to real date-type when I added it to Mongo database. Then I don't have to convert it in query.

```
 db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
         {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" : "$date", "_id":0 }}
         ])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Invalid Query**  missing "" for $toDate

```
db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
 {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" :  {"$toDate":"2018-03-03"}, "_id":0 }}
 ])
```

**Correct Query :**

```
db.sensordata.aggregate ( [      
 {"$project" :   {  "name" : "$name",   "value" : "$value",  "ts" :  {"$toDate":"2018-03-03"}, "_id":0 }}
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the date was in "string" format in my database.
The following query might work.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {"$project" :{
        "name" : "<Your_Value_Name>",
         "value" : "$<Your_Actual_Value>",  
         "ts" : {"$toDate":"$<Your_Data_Time_Value>"},  
         "_id" : 0} 
    }
])
```